# Python discord bot - trying to kick all users

Tags: python, node.js, bots, discord

I have a discord server that has suffered a coup d'état because the owner account was inactive for to long.

I wish to modify the bot before it is replaced to allow me to issue a command that will kick all members and send them an invite to a replacement server, first checking the member for a role that can be kicked.

I am least familiar with python but have only found leads for similar steps using python.

I am having permission issues with the kickem python examples I have used.
When calling the command my console reports permission problems.

> `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions`

I definitely have kick permissions. So my guess is that it first hitting members higher in the hierarchy than myself which is causing the error. Since I cant kick the new owner etc..

So I tried to add a search for specific roles but I couldn't get it to work with a list of variables. It kept getting complains of not being defined, etc. I have no idea how python would handle that.

```
# KICKEM

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kickem(ctx):
        guild=ctx.message.guild
        for member in tuple(guild.members):
                ## Try to find the role and skip those higher
                role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'leader', ctx.message.guild.roles)
                if role in member.roles:   
                        print("Kickem skip leader")
                ## Not sure how to check other roles before moving on.
                else:
                        await member.kick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your permissions are not the issue, as the bot is the one doing the kicking. Check it's role and ensure it has Administrator and/or Kick privileges.

Comment: I am positive the role has kick permissions. It is not in the administrator role, though.